# How do I get Windows 8 to properly default to the best resolution of my monitor?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, graphics-card, resolution

After installing Windows 8(.1) I have the following problem:

I have the [LG-W2243S](http://www.lg.com/za/monitors/lg-W2243S-PF-widescreen-computer-monitor) monitor. I got a `PowerColor PCS+ HD7870 GHz Myst. Edition` GPU, which I have installed the latest drivers from: `14.501.1003`. Every time I boot up my computer I have to open `AMD Catalyst Control Center`, uncheck the `EDID (Extended Display Identification Data` checkbox and set the resolution through there.
Only then I can get the right resolution, 1920x1080. When I boot up I only have 1600x1200.

I've tried Google and also looked on SuperUser before posting, I found several threads/questions but all said that I required to download the latest GPU drivers, which I already have. Is it possible that it is because my `EDID` being overwritten?

How do I get Windows to use the best resolution by default?

Comment: Try this: http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU - Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) allows custom resolutions to be defined for both AMD/ATI and NVIDIA GPUs by creating EDID overrides directly in the registry without having to deal with inf files.

Comment: Is it safe to use?

Comment: I never used it myself.

Comment: @TheDutchMan I've used it for adding an overclocked resolution for an LG panel to CCC. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sunk818 I've fixed the problem by using the [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU). With the tool I fixed it in 60 seconds.